# ArcGIS treats two similar projections definition differently

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-pro, prj, equal-area

I am about to recreate a global grid in ArcMAP, based on the Behrmann projection I though.
The map I want to recreate has this definition (in the .prj file):

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Cylindrical_Equal_Area",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Cylindrical_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",0.0],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Which I though was the exact same as ArcMAPs Behrmann projection:

```
PROJCS["World_Behrmann",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Behrmann"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

But ArcMap treats them slightly differently and can project one to the other. And they don't exactly line up. What is the difference?

Comment: Above and beyond the name, one has a standard parallel of 30N.

Comment: @Vince Behrmann has hard-coded standard parallels of +/-30, so the 2 cases should be equivalent. OP, I'm betting that because you're using a raster, there's a bit of jiggle going on. What's the cell size and start points in the two cases?

Comment: Melita - Is the 30S standard parallel in `Cylindrical_Equal_Area` snapping to 0 because it isn't specified?

Comment: I think I've solved the problem. ArcGIS Pro sees the two projections as "different", therefore it makes an automatic projection of one to the other (which is 1:1) in the display. But since the raster I was working with was overextending above 90 deg North, the on-the-fly-projection "fixed" that error. Therefore the definition was important in this case.

Comment: @Vince I think the 30 deg true scale parallel is implicit in Arc's definition of Behrmann, and regarding the Cylindrical_Equal_Area, there only needs to be one standard parallel set in the definition as far as I understand.